# Usb Folder is empty but full in size

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have some important data on my USB whenever it's mounted it shows that it has 60GB worth of data in the properties, however, the folder shows that it's empty. Whenever I open the directory in the terminal and do `ls` I get

> ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error